# Flyback power supply - 132 kHz radiated magnetic field issue

Tags: power-supply, flyback, ac-dc, magnetic-flux

I request your expertise on a radiated magnetic field around 132 kHz (low frequency) on a Flyback power supply.

I'm using the [LNK3694](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/328/linkswitch-xt2_family_datasheet-1082903.pdf) driver with a switching frequency around 66 kHz. Using a circular antenna placed at 0 cm from the power supply, I have radiated emissions around 10 dBμA/m at 66 kHz, and also second fourth... harmonic.

I want to lower this level to -2 dBμA/m. I tried with copper strip shielding, Fe (ferromagnetic) shielding around the transformer without good results.

Is this radiation coming from the driver or the transformer?
Should I shield the driver instead of the transformer?

As the switching frequency cannot be changed, what shield or small modification do you suggest to lower this emissions at those frequencies?

[image: Typical application circuit from datasheet]

Comment: Stackup? Layout? Connectors? You must minimize current loop areas.

Comment: The emitter area is like that of the antenna. The smaller the area, the lower the H field

Comment: I tried with the dev board from the manufacturer, you can found the layout in the datasheet https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/328/linkswitch-xt2_family_datasheet-1082903.pdf 
The PCB is a 2 layers. No connector on the PCB. 
the source of emission is the driver or the transformer? 
The Antenna is part of the magnetic emissions test setup, is not part of the PCB.
Thank you!